# How Can I speed Up this Sub? Copy and Paste from last column to another one

Tags: excel, vba

I m working on a file with about 1200 rows and more than 171 columns. I am trying to consolidate some data and the following Sub is a part of a bigger work. I ended up in having the sales data in different columns (nothing we can do about it - this is a consequence of a text to column transformation). So what I am doing is taking for each row the last data (which is my sales) and move them into the same column but this is very time consuming. I am wondering if you have some tips to make this process faster:

```
Sub MoveSales()
Dim DestinationWs As Worksheet
Dim MyRange As Range
Dim destinationLastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim row_no As Long
Set DestinationWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Testing")
destinationLastRow = DestinationWs.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For row_no = 2 To destinationLastRow

Dim lColumn As Long, ColLetter As String
lColumn = DestinationWs.Cells(row_no, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
ColLetter = Split(Cells(1, lColumn).Address, "$")(1)

Set MyRange = DestinationWs.Range(ColLetter & row_no)
For Each cell In MyRange
cell.Copy
DestinationWs.Range("FP" & row_no).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Next cell
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Thank you

Comment: This is doable with a formula, or if you use VBA, can be faster using a `Variant` array (read more [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx)).

Comment: `ColLetter = Split(Cells(1, lColumn).Address, "$")(1)` and `Set MyRange = DestinationWs.Range(ColLetter & row_no)` is slow. Instead just do `Set MyRange = DestinationWs.Cells(row_no,lcolumn)` no need to parse a string.

Comment: Also you could skip the clipboard: `DestinationWs.Range("FP" & row_no).Value = cell.Value`, no need to `Copy` or `PasteSpecial`.

Comment: Also using the clipboard is slow.  You could just do `DestinationWs.Range("FP" & row_no).VAlue = DestinationWs.Cells(row_no,lcolumn)`

Comment: Also the `For Each cell In MyRange` is not needed as there is only one cell ever in `Myrange`